# Why does the charge required on each plate of a capacitor to maintain a certain voltage decrease with the distance between the plates?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, capacitance

The $Q$ charge and the voltage $V$ of a capacitor are linked by $$Q=C\times V$$

For a parallel plate capacitor $C\propto \frac{1}{d}$. This implies for a given voltage $V$ between the plates, the  charge $Q$ will also be proportional to $\frac{1}{d}$. In other words, the farther the plates are from each other, the less charges they will need to have on their surface to maintain the prescribed voltage. Why is it so?

I tried to understand why by going back to the definition of the potential difference:

$$V = \int \mathbf{E}\cdot\text d\mathbf l$$

So for a fixed $V$, the $\mathbf E$-field must decrease if we want to increase the distance between the plates. But obviously the $\mathbf E$-field is generated by the charges themselves, so this is just a restatement of the fact that the charges decrease.

Comment: Would you please elaborate a little more.

Comment: @Unique Sure, what do you want me to add further details on?

Comment: "But obviously the -field is generated by the charges themselves, so this is just a restatement of the fact that the charges decrease." Are you not, by this statement, answering the question that you posed? It is essentially the $correct$ answer, (though I'd invoke Gauss's law to justify the proportionality between $Q$ and $E$).

Comment: @PhilipWood Is right. You answered your own question right there at the end...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it helps but everything happens "as if" the potential difference was used to drag away two charges $-q$ and $q$ at a distance $d$ apart. So a restatement is that the same potential can only drag away  $q/2$ and $-q/2$ over a longer distance $2d$, for instance.